# Sum column when creating table

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the following data frame in **R**:

```
   origin destination amount
1       1           2     50
2       1           2    100
3       1           2     20
4       1           3    100
5       2           3     30
6       2           3     50
7       2           1     20
8       3           2     10
9       3           2     40
10      3           1     50
```

And want to get it in a table like this:

```
     1   2   3
   1 0  170 100
   2 20  0   80
   3 50  50  0
```

I assume it should be the `table` function but this only gets me the following:

```
   1 2 3
 1 0 3 1
 2 1 0 2
 3 1 2 0
```

and I can't figure out how I get the count of the `amount`column as the value in the contiguency table. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `xtabs`

```
 xtabs(amount~origin+destination, df1)
 #        destination
 #origin   1   2   3
 #     1   0 170 100
 #     2  20   0  80
 #     3  50  50   0
```

Or use `tapply` amd replace `NA` with `0`

```
 with(df1, tapply(amount, list(origin, destination), FUN=sum))
```

Or as @David Arenburg mentioned, this could be also done with packages like `reshape2`, `tidyr`

```
 library(reshape2)
 acast(df1, origin~destination, value.var='amount', sum)
```

Comment: Are you going to add `dcast` and `spread` or you will leave it to the Hadleyverse fans ? :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for reminding me.  I was thinking only about the base R options as the OP was having troubles with table

Comment: @DavidArenburg `spread` gives error with Duplicate identifiers.  So, it may need a couple of steps to get it right.  I will leave it open for the fan club :-)